# Modify window tags in AwesomeWM

Tags: window-manager, awesome-wm

Let's say I have a browser window and Inkscape open in tag "1" and I want to move Inkscape to tag "2", what do I do? I checked the man pages, to no avail. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You focus on Inkscape and do Shift+Mod4+2.